# cross validation on a KNN model

Tags: r, machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm new to this topic and reading around hasn't helped much. 
I have reduced the dimensions in my original dataset using PCA.

I want to train my data to then try and identify a class which has not been previously seen.

I decided to use the k-nearest-neighbour (KNN) algorithm. I would like to cross validate this KNN model to find the optimum value for `K`, i.e `k` for the KNN not for `k`-fold, although i would also like to use the `k`-fold to cross validate.

I am using `R` to do the analysis.

Any advise on where i can gather more information on this topic and proceed 
to apply `k`-fold in the below code will be much appreciated.

p.s. i have used a arbitrary k value in the model.

code:

```
setwd("/Users/hp/Desktop/")

dat <- read.csv("data.csv")
dat_PCA <- dat[,c(1:63)]
dat_PCA_woC <- dat[, c(2:63)]


dat_PCA <- dat_PCA[sample(nrow(dat_PCA)), ]

training_data <- dat_PCA_woC[1:54, ]
testing_data <- dat_PCA_woC[55:63, ]
training_class <- dat_PCA[1:54, 1 ]
testing_class <- dat_PCA[55:63, 1 ]

model <- knn(train = training_data, test = testing_data,cl=training_class, k=7)
```

many thanks,
hp

Comment: In knn, a new datapoint is classified based on already "seen" samples from the training data. Per definition then, you can not classify a class correctly which has not been seen before.